# Block Website (either from PHP or from .htaccess) without having a list of IPs?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Basically I would like to temporarily block (for 1 week, I'll remove it manually afterwards) access from the Country 'Italy'.
Is there any way I can access the country 'Italy' or 'IT' from the IP without having to write thousands of IPs in the .htaccess File?

I have found some websites but they all just recommend blocking bunch of IPs in the .htaccess.

Also, I do **not** want to completely block the access, **it's enough if I can show "Page is under maintenance" for people in the country 'Italy'** on specific pages.

Thanks

Comment: What has Italy done to you?

Comment: With cloudfare, you can use `if( $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"] == 'IT){ echo "Denied";}`

Answer (score 0):

Look at [maxmind](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/) product. They have one free database. You can install geoip `apt-get install geoip` and configure your .htaccess like this [example](https://htaccess.wordpress.com/2009/10/05/allow-block-country-htaccess/)

Comment: I actually have never installed something, I always use .js files - is that fine?
It's on an external webspace where the hoster only gives me FTP Access.

Comment: this is valid only if the OP has ssh access and his OS is debian based

Comment: You can use an external free service like [hostip](http://www.hostip.info/use.html)

Comment: @MrFreezer Great tip, but unfortunately it doesn't recognize my IP so I think that website is outdated..